# Declaration of generic Iterators

Tags: java, generics, iterator, raw-types

I am programming a class called graph and I am representing the directed graph by a Hashmap. I want to create a method that prints out the whole graph in the following way:

```
key1: value13, valeue17, ..
key2: value21, ...
```

where value13 is the value of the node3 to which node1(key1) is pointing to.
So, for something like 1->2->3, and 2 pointing also to 4 I need:

```
1: 2
2: 3,4
```

my code looks like this:

```
public class Graph<T>{
  Map<Node<T>, List<Node<T>>> graph;

  //constructors and methods

  void printGraph(){
    System.out.println(graph.keySet().iterator().next().value); // is printing 7
    Iterator itKey = graph.keySet().iterator();
    System.out.println(itKey.next()); // printing Graph$Node@15db9742
    System.out.println(itKey.next().value); //error
    while(itKey.hasNext()){
    //code
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph<Integer> graph = new Graph<>();
    Node<Integer> n1 = new Node<>(7);
    Node<Integer> n2 = new Node<>(2);
    graph.connect(n1, n2);
    graph.printGraph();
  }
}
```

my problem arises in the method `printGraph()`, where I define an `Iterator`. What I want to do is create an Iterator
on the set of keys, and for every key then create an iterator that will print all the values. As you can see, if I try to print `System.out.println(graph.keySet().iterator().next().value);`
I get a 7, which makes sense because it is the value of my first key in my `keySet()`. If I the do it on an other way, initializing the iterator, `Iterator itKey = graph.keySet().iterator();`, this is an iterator pointing on a `Node`:

```
System.out.println(itKey.next()); // printing Graph$Node@15db9742
```

Although, if I try to print its value:

```
System.out.println(itKey.next().value); //error
```

I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(itKey.next().value);
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable value
  location: class Object
1 error
```

shouldn't this be the same thing? Why is the error arising?

Comment: Does this question boil down to how do I print a `Map` where the key is `Node` and the value is  `List<Node<T>>` ?

Comment: Actually the problem is more dealing with iterators, it's applied on this printing issue, but the question is not really that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a compilation error, because your `Iterator itKey` has a raw type; so calls to `itKey.next()` will return an `Object`. You want to specify the right type for your iterator, so that `iterator.next()` has return type `Node`.

In your code, just change the type for the `itKey` variable

```
  void printGraph() {
    System.out.println(graph.keySet().iterator().next().value);
    // use the non-raw type here
    Iterator<Node<T>> itKey = graph.keySet().iterator();
    System.out.println(itKey.next());
    System.out.println(itKey.next().value); 
    while (itKey.hasNext()) {
      // code
    }
  }
```

---

The line `System.out.println(graph.keySet().iterator().next().value);` compiles, because no type information is lost. Looking at the types involved:

- the `graph` variable has type `Map<Node<T>, List<Node<T>>>`
- `graph.keySet()` has type `Set<Node<T>>`
- `graph.keySet().iterator()` has type `Iterator<Node<T>>`
- `graph.keySet().iterator().next()` has type `Node<T>`

and since the type for the last `next()` is a `Node`, we can get its `value`.

Comment: ok, but why does then the first line know which type I mean? When I use graph.iterator().next().value; I mean, what is the intrinsic difference? Why does one understand the type and the other not?

Comment: I've edited the answer; in the first case, no type is lost. So we end up with an iterator on `Node`s. But if you declare `Iterator` (without the generic type) instead of `Iterator<Node>`, then the iterator will be an iterator on `Object`s;

Answer (score 0):

You should provide Generic Iterator rather non generic. If non generic its return **Object** type as element and then you need to typecast it to Node which is not good, so it is better to define the type while getting Iterator instance.

```
 Iterator<Node<T>> itKey = graph.keySet().iterator();

 while(itKey.hasNext()){
         System.out.println(itKey.next().value);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
itKey.next().value
```

gives **error** because iterator **doesn't** know what `value` is. *Probably* casting the `itKey.next()` to `Node` would work *but thats not the most ideal way* to print out your graph.

You can use below method for the same. It uses entry set to iterate over the `graph` map.

**The `printGraph` function:**

```
void printGraph() {
    for (Map.Entry<Node<T>, List<Node<T>>> entry : graph.entrySet()) {
        Node<T> fromNode = entry.getKey();
        System.out.print(fromNode.value + " ->");
        for (Node<T> toNode : entry.getValue())
            System.out.print(" " + toNode.value);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**`main` function:**

```
Node<Integer> n1 = new Node<>(1);
Node<Integer> n2 = new Node<>(2);
Node<Integer> n3 = new Node<>(3);
Node<Integer> n4 = new Node<>(4);
Node<Integer> n5 = new Node<>(5);

Graph<Integer> graph = new Graph<>();
graph.connect(n1, n2);
graph.connect(n1, n3);
graph.connect(n4, n5);

graph.printGraph();
```

**which prints:**

```
4 -> 5
1 -> 2 3
```